# How to check if a nested list contains a particular value C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got a nested list with numbers of lists inside. I wanna check if this nested list contains a particular string value and it does not matter which list is the value stored in .

```
                        if (!checkList.Any(s => s == "aaa"))
                        {
                          // do sth
                        }
```

the above is to check normal list but not nested list, can anyone give me the answer for nested list?

Comment: At least show the declaration of that "nested list".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a nested `Any`:

```
if (!checkList.Any(innerList => innerList.Any(s => s == "aaa")))
```

Alternatively, you may use a `SelectMany` to flatten your list:

```
if (!checkList.SelectMany(innerList => innerList).Any(s => s == "aaa"))
```